# how does angular deal with elements with multiple directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If an element has multiple directives, one with `scope:false`, one with `scope:true`, one with `scope:{}`, how does angular deal with this element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include all three directives asking for all three scope options on the same element, you get an error. `true` and `false` are compatible and use the same scope, but adding `{}` causes:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [isolatedScope, trueScope]
asking for new/isolated scope on:
<div false-scope="" true-scope="" isolated-scope="">
```

In this case, `true` and `{}` conflict when `true` tries to create a new, inheriting scope and `{}` tries to create a new, isolated scope, which is reasonable and perhaps expected. The [$compile docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object) say:

> If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created.

If you have multiple directives with `scope: true`, they're fine and you get just one, but `scope: {}` asks for a different kind, and Angular can't produce both. Directives can be declared with `priority`, so they could have quietly picked a winner, but that would lead to all sorts of surprises, so they wisely decided to shout about it.

---

Here's [a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ro3zDbvUf2D1kYwAH5CC) demonstrating it. I put all three scopes on a single `div`, then declared data in each of them using data available in the parent scope. If you comment out the `scope: {}`, it works fine and you can see the `false` and `true` scopes sharing. I haven't investigated whether `false` or `true` won out, but I suspect `true` because it indicates to `$compile` that a new scope is wanted.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div false-scope true-scope isolated-scope>
    <b>False directive</b>
    <ul>
      <li>Loaded: {{ falseDirectiveLoaded }}</li>
      <li>Data: {{ falseDirectiveData }}</li>
    </ul>
    <b>True directive</b>
    <ul>
      <li>Loaded: {{ trueDirectiveLoaded }}</li>
      <li>Data: {{ trueDirectiveData }}</li>
    </ul>
    <b>Isolated directive</b>
    <ul>
      <li>Loaded: {{ isolatedDirectiveLoaded }}</li>
      <li>Data: {{ isolatedDirectiveData }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.one = 1;
  $scope.two = 2;
  $scope.three = 3;
});

app.directive('falseScope', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.falseDirectiveLoaded = true;
      scope.falseDirectiveData = [scope.one, scope.two, scope.three];
    }
  }
});

app.directive('trueScope', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.trueDirectiveLoaded = true;
      scope.trueDirectiveData = [scope.one, scope.two, scope.three];
    }
  }
});

app.directive('isolatedScope', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.isolatedDirectiveLoaded = true;
      scope.isolatedDirectiveData = [scope.one, scope.two, scope.three];
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As JS uses [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), scope can receive any kind of values though they may filter what angular accepts.

With that in mind, when angular receives the scope, I guess [it verifies the type of the argument](http://javascript.info/tutorial/type-detection), and threat it accordly.

- boolean: let you control if the scope will be inherited
- object*: let you add "new proprieties" that are bound to that directive
- others: I don't know how angular behaves if any other type, as a string, is passed

*I guess it only accepts JSON